# Utilization of RAM and CPU for normal Operations of Blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

Please suggest on how to make my Processor and RAM be fully Utilized by Blender for normal Operations like for example,  When I select about 200K faces on a large terrain and try to run "Limited Dissolve", it uses almost no GPU, 3GB RAM(out of 16GB) and only about 18% of Processor  when I check in the Task Manager Performance tab.

I am not interested in Rendering anything, because I export the meshes to other game engines... Only when I have to work with Large terrains, the system runs ok, but only Blender goes numb for 2hrs...

I killed blender about twice(even reinstalled with no addons), and when I restarted the same process, and this time run other applications, they are able to utilze 90% of CPU and 5-8GB of RAM... But only Blender is absolutely shy in using all the resources it is given....

I have also added Blender in all places where GPU can take charge, but it uses only 200mb of GPU.... of the 8GB 1050Ti...

Please Help....

Comment: Do you mean that when you try to perform some operation on your mesh it takes a very long time?

Comment: Hi @AllenSimpson  yes, when I do a limited dissolve on a mesh with over 11million quads, it takes almost 2.5-3hrs... My main problem is that blender is limiting itself to 18% of the processor/CPU, and almost no utilization of GPU...

Comment: @AllenSimpson is there a way to make it utilize all 100% of the CPU, without any restrictions, because I am trying to make a game, and Blender is the only thing I can afford, and not maya or 3dmax

Comment: @AllenSimpson  now I am not talking about rendering, because there are a few addons for that... but normal processing of simple operations... 3dmax and maya, take up 100% of utilization, and give results much faster than this damn thing... I sit in front of the computer, where blender is frozen for hours while dealing with large meshes

Comment: I understand, this makes it a lot more clear, thanks.

Comment: @AllenSimpson you are welcome... and pls let me know if you know of a addon,, or some settings, which can make this restriction of using 18% CPU, go away...needs to push to 100%..  Blender is now being funded by large corps, and the devs are only working for them...they are senseless thinking that all blender users have Xeon processors where 18% is good enough... They have stopped thinking about the common man, whose machine could be a 2yr old i7(3.5Ghz).. it needs to take up complete CPU to accomplish anything..Money runs the world, and now even the open source blender..

Comment: I don't really have a good answer here, but I didn't want to leave you hanging.  I do have some general knowledge I can share, though.  First, I wouldn't worry about how much RAM something is using unless you're running out.  What I suspect is happening is something that happens in games sometimes.  Your processor is waiting on something from memory, which is a much slower operation compared to processor cycles, so the processor is essentially waiting around a lot of the time.  Evidently there's some inefficiency here if other apps can do it faster.

Comment: With a large mesh (certainly not 11m quads, though) I can get a limited dissolve operation to use about 55% of my cpu, so this seems to come down to system configuration.  You often hear people say that blender doesn't like handling meshes over 1.5 to 2m verts.  You appear to be way over what most people would consider tenable, apart from everything else. :p

Comment: @AllenSimpson , thanks for your views :)  I understand, and I really hope the Blender guys create a mechanism where we can allocate the amount of resources we want it to handle... I cleared the temp files and all,, restarted the system, made sure no garbage programs run from anything other than what windows needs on os level, and then ran blender again...  it still doesn't think it needs more than 19%  while I am staring at it, without blinking, but the surprise though, it completed in 1hr53mins..

Comment: I am sure that it is something to do with the threads that it allocates per operation, and something like "Limited Dissolve" may take only one thread, so I guess unless someone  knows how to work with thread manipulation, Blender will be what it is ... I like it, even with that attitude... When I write to devs, none of them bother to respond... ofcourse, so many write, and I am not even a funder... if anyone feels that have a way to work around this, pls help with something... Thanks...

Comment: @Lokkii9 perhaps you can try setting the priority of blender to high or maybe even more in task manager